# Compile with low SDK build tools version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to build project with lower SDK version. Got warning:

```
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
```

Should I somehow install lower Gradle plugin version? How I can do that?

Comment: Why would you compile for API 25 anyways? If you absolutely want API 25, you have to degrade the Gradle plugin, but there's not really a problem with it

Answer (score 3):

You can change Androd gradle plugin version in your `build.gradle` file of project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

You can look to [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove this one line from the module's `build.gradle` to get rid of the warning message:

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

The latest version matching the `targetSdkVersion` will be used then. Manually setting the `buildToolsVersion` is definitely not required anymore - and downgrading the Gradle plugin is also pointless, because you'd need to downgrade the whole IDE, in order to have matching versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore this warning as android studio is taking care of using right build tool version 'Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3'.

You can also modify your app/build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {

    buildToolsVersion = 28.0.3

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Firstly, this is just a warning and you can ignore it. 
This warning will not create any problem for basic development.

Secondly, this warning appears when somehow your build.gradle is using 25.0.1 as build tools version, which in turn can be from any library/package that you have used and might not be from any of your build.gradle files

In order to remove this warning completely, you need to make sure that all your module level build.gradle files contains the following lines :

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    targetSdkVersion 28

Or, you can lower the gradle version in your project level build.gradle file (The reference you posted in  your question) with this line

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}

Hope it helps you :)
```